# Create Child View based on selection in Drop Down List

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, dropdownbox

I am using MVC 5 and I have the following situation:

I have a drop down list on a view that changes the child view that is displayed based on the selection in the list. This needs to change on the onchange or similar event. The selections in the list are populated from a database and has the following properties:

1. Link ID - Int (to be used as a value for the selection (must be saved on the main view)
2. Link Text - What is to be displayed in the drop down list.
3. LinK URL - The address of the child view action (made up of different areas, controllers, and actions)

In essence, when the list changes, it must call the URL (passing the model) and return the content to a targeted placeholder div on the page

Any Ideas on where to get started on this one?

Comment: If you want the update on the same page (no postback) then this is a basic Ajax/jQuery client-side problem and not really a Razor issue. *You really need to show code/views of what you have tried so far. SO is about looking at code and suggesting fixes (not writing it for you to spec)* :)

Comment: I agree about your comment on code / views that I have tried, but at this point I was just looking for a place to get started. Thanks for the suggestion. I wasn't sure if I needed to jump into jquery or if there was something simple in razor. This gives me a place to start. I will update this question as I move forward with the solution. Thanks!

Comment: You may be able to combine onchange events with an update panel to do it in MVC, but it will probably wind up simpler with jQuery (as it is a common pattern).

Comment: We were able to get this working using ajax to call the child view. Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to get this working using ajax to call the child view. Thanks for the pointers.